# Estilo de botón en vb

Tags: vba, vb

Tengo un botón que llama una función que da números al azar cada que le dan click. Lo que quiero es que no se "note" cuando el usuario da click en el botón, es decir, que no parezca que se unde ni cambie de color al presionarlo, saben como hacer eso?

Comment: los botones ya traen esa funcionalidad, bien puedes usar un label para eso

Comment: Por qué no usar un `Label` o un `PictureBox`?

Comment: @Manny, entonces es imposible evitarlo?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez porque me permite modificar el tamaño de la label y se nota mucho la diferencia :/

Comment: @Aby Claro que si permite cambiar el tamaño del `Label`, cambia la propiedad `AutoSize` a `false` y así puedes ponerle el tamaño que quieras.

Comment: Muchas gracias @J.Rodríguez :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta solución es un poco cutre, pero hace exactamente lo que quieres, sin complicar demasiado.

Yo he hecho un ejemplo muy sencillo. He creado una macro que dice "Hola mundo", y la he asignado a un botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate que el botón está hundido cuando hice clic.

El truco consiste en hacer un pantallazo del botón, y meterlo como imagen. Recórtala justo por el borde. Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pégala en tu archivo y asígnale una macro. Funcionará igual que un botón, pero no se hundirá al hacer click. Te quedará algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar un control Label (etiqueta) con algunas propiedades le das la apariencia de botón:

- BackStyle: 1 - fmBackStyleOpaque
- SpecialEffect: 1 - fmSpecialEffectRaised
- TextAlign: 2 - fmTextAlignCenter

Y utilizar el evento Click como con el botón:

```vb
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    MsgBox "Saludos", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Click en Label"
End Sub
```